# Javascript: How to render previous breakpoints from the array of breakpoints

Tags: javascript, arrays

Javascript: How to render previous breakpoints from the array of mediatypes.

```
function getCurrentBreakpoint(mediaType) {
  const mediaTypes = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "infinity"];
  //suppose current mediaType is `infinity` 
  // I have to return mediaType as `xl` . always one prevoius state from the current.


}
```

currently it can be achieved  by using

```
if ... else or by switch case


 let breakpoint;
  switch (mediaType) {
    case "infinity":
      breakpoint = "xl";
      break;
    case "xl":
      breakpoint = "lg";
      break;
    case "lg":
      breakpoint = "md";
      break;
    case "md":
      breakpoint = "sm";
      break;
    default:
      breakpoint = "xs";
  }
```

any suggestion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) as follows to return previous element relative to the one passed in parameter:

```js
function getCurrentBreakpoint(mediaType) {
  const mediaTypes = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "infinity"];
  let i = mediaTypes.indexOf(mediaType);
  return mediaTypes[i - (i == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
}

console.log(getCurrentBreakpoint('infinity'));
console.log(getCurrentBreakpoint('sm'));
console.log(getCurrentBreakpoint('xs'));
```

Comment: this is bang on.. could you please explain me this.. it will be helpful fr me.

Comment: when you use `indexOf` with array and pass an element, it finds the position of the element in the array. we then reduce the index by one and access the element with that reduced index to get the previous element

Comment: how can i succeed over edge case like if the  `mediaType` is `undefined` it should return `undefined` or if it is `xs` it should return `xs` ?
Any help.

Comment: you could check `mediaTypes.indexOf(mediaType)` against `mediaTypes.length`, that should cover the undefined case as well

Comment: could you please update  your code? for better understanding of this to me.

Comment: please check the updated code, I've added ternary operator to check `i == 0` and `getCurrentBreakpoint(undefined)` is handled already